# Google Sheets - How to conditionally copy an entire column?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I'm trying to write a formula to copy an entire column from one sheet to another, depending on a condition. The current formula I have is:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFS(Settings!B7="Combined MPG", 'Raw Data'!B:B, Settings!B7="City MPG", 'Raw Data'!C:C, Settings!B7="Highway MPG", 'Raw Data'!D:D))
```

This formula only fills the cell that it is in, instead of its column. Does anybody know what I did wrong?

As an example, if the condition `Settings!B7="City MPG"` is `true`, I would like for the column that this formula is in to be filled with the data from column `D` in the sheet `Raw Data`.

Comment: array formulas need every element to be parallel in scope. Your IFS formula is saying (in plain English), "If one cell equals something, return a whole column of cells"; but array formulas generally need "If one cell equals something, return one result" or "If a whole range equals something, return a whole range of equal size of results." You've further complicated things by saying, "If one cell in sheet B equals something, return a whole column the length of sheet C and place it into a column of potentially different length in sheet A."

Comment: The parallel structure necessary to achieve what you want to do IS possible, but it's complex. I'd need to see your sheet. If you'd like to share a link to your sheet (or a copy of it), being sure to set the link's Share permission to "Anyone with the link can edit," I'll take a look.

Answer (score 1):

You could give the `QUERY` function ago:

`=IF(Settings!B7="Combined MPG",QUERY('Raw Data'!D:D),"")`

This works fine for me so hopefully will sort your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to make it work. It's slightly counter intuitive, but when I added a new condition that can never be true using a parallel array formula at the beginning of the IFS formula, it made the entire formula work. Here is the updated formula:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFS(Settings!A:A="thiswillneverexist","",Settings!B7="Combined MPG", 'Raw Data'!B:B, Settings!B7="City MPG", 'Raw Data'!C:C, Settings!B7="Highway MPG", 'Raw Data'!D:D))
```